# Prove that $\gcd(4^n + 1, 3) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\gcd(4^n + 1, 3) = 1$ for all $n \in \textbf N$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $3$ is prime, the gcd can  only be $1$ or $3$. If it were $3$,  then $4^n+1\equiv 0 \bmod 3$

But $4\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, so $4^n+1\equiv 1^n+1\equiv 2 \not \equiv 0 \bmod 3$.

Hence it must be the case that $\gcd(4^n+1,3)=1$

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$4^n+1=(3+1)^n+1=3m +2$; m∈N

So the remainder of $(4^n+1)/3$ is 2 and (3, 2)=1, theretofore:

$gcd(4^n+1, 3)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is the same as showing that $4^n+1$ is not a multiple of $3$, which is the same as showing that $4^n$ cannot leave a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Since $4\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ , $4^n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ then $4^n+1\equiv2\pmod{3}$. This proves the result right!?

Comment: Yes. I wasn't sure from your question whether you knew this notation or not, so I avoided it.

Comment: Ohh i thought of posting it, with the question itself but i thought may be some better way will be available. Thanks for the help ! +1

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.  Or if you can't do it, just try it.

$3$ is prime so $\gcd(4^n+1,3) = 1$ or $3$.

So $\gcd(4^n+1,3) =3 \iff 3|4^n+1$.

Is it possible for $3$ to divide $4^n + 1$?  You should have some ideas about that.

........

$4= 3+1$ and $4^n= (3+1)^n \equiv 1^n\pmod 3$.

So $4^n+1\equiv 1^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.  So there $3\not \mid 4^n+1$ ever and $\gcd(4^n+1, 3) = 1$.

If you aren't comfortabe with $\pmod 3$ notation just note $4^n + 1 = (3+1)^n + 1= (\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} 3^k)+1 + 1= 3*(\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}3^{k-1}) + 2$.  So $3|3*(\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}3^{k-1})$ and $3\not \mid 2$ so $3\not \mid 3*(\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}3^{k-1}) + 2= 4^n+1$.

And if $3\not \mid 4^n+1$ then no other factor of $3$ (other than $1$) exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the finite ring $\{0, 1, 2\}$, this question becomes trivially simple. Since $4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $4$ becomes $1$. And $1^n = 1$ regardless of what $n$ is, so $1^n + 1 = 2$  regardless of what $n$ is.

It gets a little more interesting for $\gcd(2^n + 1, 3)$. If $n$ is odd, then $2^n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and therefore $2^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. But if $n$ is even, $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and so $2^n + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. And remember that if $n$ is even, $$2^n = 4^{\frac{n}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$4^n+1=4^n-1+2=(4-1)(4^{n-1}+...+4+1) +2$$